# Different outputs from one comp

Tags: after-effects

Coming from a node based editor, I am trying to find the best way to export multiple outputs from a single AE comp.

For example, in my comp, I have 3-4 different masks that's applied to overall comp. I want to export seperate sequences , each with the unique mask applied to the image.

What's the fastest way to accomplish this in AE ?

thanks!

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to re-use the comp several times, but apply different masks to it? For each individual mask just drag the comp into a new comp, and apply the mask.